Can the &. nesting selector be used without precompiling?
I am trying to create a card flip using vanilla CSS and Js using the &. selector to target an element that also includes the parent as a compound selector.
There is an example here which is using stylus...
https://codepen.io/colebemis/pen/WNKdNj?editors=1111
I have tried to simplify the example that uses only vanilla CSS & JavaScript here...
https://codepen.io/dickkirkland/pen/JjVwJdB
In my attempt to flip the card the 2 <div>s aren't as seamless and seem to flip independently vs. the first example where the card visually looks just like one card with a front and a back.
Is the JavaScript in my example firing too fast or does the nesting with &.flipped have to be included so that the animation will be seen as 1 card?
I can't seem to use or the Codepen editor won't allow me to use the direct &. approach with plain CSS.
Is there a a different way to achieve this animation?
Any advice or insight would be greatly appreciated.
The HTML is
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">See More Stats</div>
    <div class="back">-- Member Stats --</div>
  </div>
</div>

with the CSS
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #00A5F7;
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;  
  perspective: 800px;
  border-radius: 4px; 
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  cursor: pointer;
}
  

div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font: 16px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  color: #47525D;
}

/*  .back {
   transform: rotateY(180deg);

   &.flipped {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
   }

} */

.back {
   transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flipped {
   transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

and Js
//     $('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
//   });

let container = document.querySelector('.container');
let card = document.querySelector('.card');
  
 container.addEventListener('click', function () {
    card.classList.toggle('flipped');
 });

In addition to the links above you can see the CSS &. that is commented out. I don't want to use jQuery and have commented this out in the Js as well.

https://jsfiddle.net/dtokzmrL/ - works fine for me in current Chrome and Firefox.

@CBroe Thanks. Did the same on JSFiddle and it doesn't seem to honor the &.

https://jsfiddle.net/aedtng95/1/

You changed a styling in your css. In the original the selector is .card div whereas in your example it is just div (targeting every div in the document)

Thanks. I think the answer below is the same explanation? I appreciate your time.

There is whitespace that you are not taking into account in your pure css code. The actual post-compiled css should look like
.card div {...}
.card .back {...}
.card.flipped {...}

because the div,.back and &.flipped are nested inside the .card rule.
Demo at https://codepen.io/Gabriele-Petrioli/pen/poBGdwR

If you use a modern browser that supports CSS nesting you should write your css as
.card{ 
 ...

 .div {...}
 .back {...}
 &.flipped {...}
}

demo at: https://codepen.io/Gabriele-Petrioli/pen/vYMbWxP

Thank you so much. I really appreciate this answer. I think I may not have understood what Stylus was actually achieving in the compiling and that was my issue too? Marked this as the answer. Have a great day.
